# String Manipulation by hiding and showing

Tags: vb.net, string

The idea is simple, if I have a string value "ABCD" then with a ButtonClick event it should randomly reveal a char while others are hidden. i.e, "*B**" another click would "AB**" and so on.

So far, my I have been stuck in a for loop.

```
    For Each c As Char In x
        y = Random.Next(0, x.IndexOf(c))
    Next
```

I'm still learning VB.NET at this phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Class Form1

    Private _indexes As Integer()
    Private _currentIndex As Integer
    Private _chars As Char()
    Private _template As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim rnd = New Random()

        _template = "ABCD"

        ' Create indexes that are randomly sorted 
        _indexes = Enumerable _
            .Range(0, _template.Length) _
            .OrderBy(Function(i) rnd.Next()) _
            .ToArray()

        'Create an array of chars with stars '****'. 
        _chars = New String("*"c, _template.Length).ToCharArray()

        _currentIndex = 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If _currentIndex < _template.Length Then
            Dim index As Integer = _indexes(_currentIndex)
            _currentIndex += 1
            _chars(index) = _template(index)
            Dim result As String = New String(_chars)
            Label1.Text = result
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You might also want tp analyse the code by using the debugger, if you are not sure what it does. The debugger allows you to execute the code step by step and to inspect the values of variables as the code executes.

Comment: It actually works but it use MessageBox instead of Console.Writeline.
How can I use the variable result in Label?

Comment: Supposedly the variable 'result' should be display on label.text property. So what I did is 

Label1.Text = result

But for some reason since it is under the for-loop, it already displayed all the characters.  Is there any additional code provided by Olivier that will just activate only by clicking the button once, then reveal the character (i.e, string "ABAC" will reaveal "-B--" after clicking a button)

Great thanks to Olivier Jacot-Descombes for the code he provided.

Comment: You have to separate the code into three parts. 1: Variables, which must be available during the whole process, must be placed in the header. 2: They must be initialized in Form_Load (or when the template text changes). 3: Finally, there is the Button_Click code, which is executed at each click, of cause without loop, since you are performing the loop manually, by clicking the button several times. I changed the example.

Answer (score 0):

I have already posted an answer where I focused on the algorithm. The algorithm code was directly integrated into a form. This works but is not a good practice. The code would be more reusable, more understandable and could be tested more easily if it was extracted to a separate class.

```
Public Class RandomTextRevealer
    Private _indexes As Integer()
    Private _currentIndex As Integer
    Private _chars As Char()
    Private _template As String
    Private _result As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal templateText As String)
        Dim rnd = New Random()

        _template = templateText

        ' Create indexes that are randomly sorted 
        _indexes = Enumerable _
         .Range(0, _template.Length) _
         .OrderBy(Function(i) rnd.Next()) _
         .ToArray()

        'Create an array of chars with stars '****'. 
        _chars = HiddenText.ToCharArray()

        _currentIndex = 0
    End Sub

    Public Function RevealNext() As String
        If _currentIndex < _template.Length Then
            Dim index As Integer = _indexes(_currentIndex)
            _currentIndex += 1
            _chars(index) = _template(index)
            _result = New String(_chars)
        End If
        Return _result
    End Function

    Public ReadOnly Property HiddenText() As String
        Get
            Return New String("*"c, _template.Length)
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

We can test the class like this in a little console application, without a form:

```
Module Programm
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim revealer = New RandomTextRevealer("Just a test")
        Console.WriteLine(revealer.HiddenText)

        For i As Integer = 1 To 12
            Console.WriteLine(revealer.RevealNext())
        Next
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Now we can integrate it in a form like this (I added a Reset-button, in order to be able to repeat the test with different random values):

```
Public Class Form2
    Dim revealer As RandomTextRevealer

    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Reset()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnReveal_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnReveal.Click
        Label1.Text = revealer.RevealNext()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnReset_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
        Reset()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Reset()
        revealer = New RandomTextRevealer("ABCD")
        Label1.Text = revealer.HiddenText
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now our form-code looks much cleaner.